# Power supply amperage to wattage conversion

Tags: power, amplifier, amperage, watts

How many amperes would be needed for a PC power supply to run around 1000 watts RMS on a class-D mono block car amplifier in my house? Are PC power supplies the best option?

Comment: A 12V 1200W PC power supply costs about the same as a mains powered 1kW class D amp, for example Behringer iNuke. So there is no cost advantage to using a 12V supply for the car amp.

Comment: Unless you are playing a sine wave or noise at 0 dBFS, expect 1/8 of average power even for compressed music. Some dubstep may briefly push it to 1/3 average power.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* the amplifier can actually deliver 1000 W output ("1000 W RMS" sounds like marketing speak; look in the amplifier's manual to find the maximum current it can actually draw), and *assuming* 80% efficiency of the class-D amplifier, you need 1250 W to feed the amplifier.

P=V·I, so *assuming* a supply voltage of 12 V for the amplifier (car battery), you need 1250/12 ≈ 105 A when using the full power of the amplifier.

This is a much higher current than even a powerful PC power supply can deliver on its 12 V output.